# Comment table mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a 'comments' table, so holds text, created, userId etc...

But a user can comment on many things.

So I cant put a foreign key to the 'Post' table as I also need to be able to comment on the 'Picture' table, what is the best practice for this?

So basically a multiple table link table?

Comment: add column `type` or `rel_table` or something else

Comment: I would consider 2 tables: post_comment and picture_comment, foreign keyed back to the respective parent table. Trying to use a one size fits all method can work, but can also cause data integrity headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment table:

```
comment(comment_id,text, created, userid, other_field,...)
```

Link table

```
link(comment_id,comment_type, refID, )
```

where `comment_type` would be the name of the table you commented on ("picture", "post",...). `comment_id` would be the id of the comment a user made. `refID` is the `id` of the table the user commented on (Post_id, Picture_id,...)

Lets say you have these table entries:

```
POST(id, some_text,other_stuff,...):
(1, "Hello Hello", "something",...)
(2, "Hey there", "something_else",...)
...
(57, "TEST TEST", "another something",...)

PICTURE(pic_id, description, other_stuff):
(4, "A cat", "something",...)
(2, "Another cat", "something_else",...)
...
(57, "finally a dog", "another something",...)
```

When a user ads a new comment:

Comment

```
(1,"What a cute cat", 2015-10-02, user24)
(3,"That something is awesome", 2015-10-02, user87)
```

link

```
(1,"Picture", 4) //That comment is about the cat (Picture ID 4)
(3, "Post",57) //That comment is about the post with ID 57
```